# Looking for examples of programmatic generation of geometries in xml3d

Tags: javascript, 3d, geometry, programmatically-created, xml3d

There are various examples [here](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/3D-UI_-_XML3D_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide) in the [specification](http://xml3d.org/xml3d/specification/5.0/) but I could not find an end-to-end example on how to start e.g. with a numerical dataset representing an object surface, construct the meshes on the fly and display in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

We have some examples of this in our [xml3d-examples](https://github.com/xml3d/xml3d-examples) repository, particularly the [wave](http://xml3d.github.io/xml3d-examples/examples/xflowWave/xflow-wave.html) example which generates and deforms a grid on the fly. The [face morphing](http://xml3d.github.io/xml3d-examples/examples/facemorph/facemorph.html) example also shows mesh deformation, the principle for generating the mesh would be basically the same.

What you'll want to do is [write an Xflow operator](http://xml3d.org/xml3d/specification/5.0/#the-compute-operator) that takes the numerical dataset as input and outputs vertex positions (and normals and face indices if necessary). The end result would look something like this:

```
<data id="mydata" compute="index, position, normal = xflow.yourOperator(input1, input2 ...)">
    <float3 id="myinput1" name="input1">...</float3>
    ...
</data>

<mesh src="#mydata" type="triangles"></mesh>
```

[Here](http://xml3d.github.io/xml3d-examples/examples/xflowWave/myxflow.js) is the operator from the wave example above, that would be a good starting point. Xflow will automatically re-compute the mesh whenever the input data changes and you could use the [setScriptValue](http://xml3d.org/xml3d/specification/5.0/#the-float-float2-float3-float4-and-float4x4-elements) function on value elements (int, float, float3 etc) to set the input data without having to dump it into the DOM as text:

```
document.getElementById("myinput1").setScriptValue(numericalData.input1);
```